# I want a popup with a cancel button. Is it a good idea to use an AJAX Popup control extender?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

Please note this is a popup and NOT modal popup. The users do not want a modal popup.
Is it a good idea to use an Ajax Popup Control extender in the following circumstances;
I want to populate a textbox. When the user clicks on it, he sees a popup window.
In the popup window you can enter value of the field, or make a selection from a drop down list. When you have decided, you can either click on a submit button to commit your changes, or click on a cancel button to ignore your changes.
By experimenting I have found how to do this, apart from the cancel button.
How do I do this? Or should I try something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out this jquery plugin

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/dialog-quickstart.html has a good example of what you are looking for